# создать глубокую ссылку telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

пытаюсь передать некий параметр при переходе с моего сайта по ссылке на telegram bot, пока для теста просто любую текстовую строку, в ссылке добавляю:

```
    <a href="http://t.me/bot_name?start=qwerty">
```

в функции бота просто пытаюсь напечатать полученное сообщение:

```
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def send_welcome(message):
        
        
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

но раз за разом получаю только /start, без передаваемого мной текста.
подскажите прошу, что делаю не так?

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/81d94687bee17b29aa017cd32a57f8be62b942ca/examples/deep_linking.py#L63 ?

Answer (score 2):

https://telegram.me/NAME_BOT?start=getCommand-123456

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def test(message):
    print(message.text)
    print(message.text.split())
    a = message.text.split()[0]
    b = message.text.split()[1]
    print(f'a: {a}, b: {b}')

>>> /start getCommand-123456
    ['/start', 'getCommand-123456']
    a: /start, b: getCommand-123456


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: `a, b = message.text.split()`? :)

Comment: не знал, что можно не указывать индекс :)